# Calculate length of fish using normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

The sizes of fish caught in a lake are known to correspond to a normal distribution where the variable X is the length of the fish in cm.

Based on previous trips it is estimated that

P(X <= 91) = 0.17 and P(X <= 137) = 0.7

Using this information, predict what proportion of the fish within the lake have a length between 91 cm and 137 cm.

How do I solve this equation? I've used a normal distribution graph but I'm stuck as to where to go next.

Comment: $P(91 \leq X \leq 137) = P(X\leq 137) - P(X\leq 91)$. This can be visually verified by drawing the pdf of the normal distribution.

Comment: thank you, but how do I work out the number without the graph say?

Answer (score 1):

You asked in the comments for you could work out the number with the graph, but I think you're misunderstanding what @BranBar was suggesting here. Rather, they're invoking a rule that applies for *any* distribution whatosever -- no graph required, but a graph may help make the idea clearer.

Presumably, you have heard that normally-distributed data has a bell shape. This isn't terribly useful right away, because you don't know what the mean $\mu$ is, so you can't really even give a good rough sketch of it.* But, we can try some possible graphs given the bell-shape idea: [image]

We know that the distribution should be centered at $\mu$, but we don't know where $\mu$ is, so we can't even sketch a picture that accurately places it in relation to the numbers 91 and 137. In the picture above, we see two possibilities for what the curve might look like, and 91 and 137 have to sit in different places for each of those pictures.

However, there's an essential *truth* that we can see in each picture. We know how to find the answer to the question, which is to take the red-striped area and subtract the green-striped area. By subtracting, we'll get the area between the two numbers, which is precisely what we want. And this worked *no matter how we drew the picture.*

The key idea is that for *any* continuous random variable $X$ (such as a normal distribution), we have
$$  \mathbb P(a \leq X \leq b) = \mathbb P(X \leq b) - \mathbb P(X \leq a)$$
and we can see why from the picture, even though we weren't sure what picture to use: by thinking about the areas, we see that "$X \leq b$" is made up of two distinct parts: "$X \leq a$", and "$a \leq X \leq b$". (Or, restated: for $X$ to be below $b$, it should be either below $a$, or between $a$ and $b$.) This justifies the equation above, which solves the problem at hand.

*Technical note: the information in the problem is enough to render the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$, but that's almost surely beyond the scope of what you're being asked to do.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thank you so much. I'm studying for my masters in Comp Sci with AI and the learning material can be quite intense.

Comment: Glad to help! If you're satisfied with this answer, please consider accepting it so that the question can be resolved in Math Stack Exchange. Happy studying!